# Why is a condition working outside a Do-Loop, but giving Type Mismatch within it

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I have a Do-Loop in some vbscript code which was definitely working when I last used it (a month or two ago). Today it's not working, with a runtime error:

> Microsfot VBScript runtime error: Type mismatch at line *{Line with the Do on it}*

Here is the original code:

```
counter = 0 
Do until objSheet.range(startCell).offset(counter) = ""     
    counter = counter + 1
Loop
```

I've tested whether the conditional should work, by adding an if statement:

```
counter = 0 
call writeLine(objSheet.range(startCell).offset(counter))    
if not objSheet.range(startCell).offset(counter) = "" then call writeLine("not blank")
Do until objSheet.range(startCell).offset(counter) = ""     
    counter = counter + 1
Loop
```

The if statement executes fine, and in my output window I get:

> 10100
>
> not blank

But then it still gets a type mismatch on the Do line, at the first attempt.

So then I tried an alternative Do Loop:

```
counter = 0
call writeLine(objSheet.range(startCell).offset(counter))   
if not objSheet.range(startCell).offset(counter) = "" then call writeLine("not blank")
    
Do 
    if objSheet.range(startCell).offset(counter) = "" then
        Exit Do
    else
        counter = counter + 1
    end if
Loop
```

It still outputs "10100, not blank", i.e. it executes the first if statement absolutely fine, but then it gets a Type Mismatch on the if statement within the Do-Loop.

**Why am I getting a type Mismatch?**

Possibly more relevant way of writing the same question: **Why does the If statement have a Type Mismatch when within a Do-Loop, but not when it's outside it?**

Comment: Where's `startCell` defined?

Comment: Looks like your comparing a integer with a string which will give you a `Type Mismatch` error. Instead of `objSheet.range(startCell).offset(counter) = ""` as a condition use `Len(objSheet.range(startCell).offset(counter) & "") < 1`.

Comment: At what iteration does it fail. When it errors out, hit "Debug" and see what the value of `counter` is. My guess is that you get through a lot of iterations before it fails. Is counter defined as an integer. Perhaps it's maxing out at 65535 (the upper bound for an integer in VBA). Instead, define it as a Long.

Comment: @JNevill That's a good point, I assumed that was the value in the cell not the iteration it got to though. Also if that was the cause wouldn't the iteration have got to `65535` before it threw an error?

Comment: Right, I'm being stupid don't do much Excel VBA COM stuff. The `Offset()` method returns a `Range` object not a string or integer, but the `Range` object has a default method of `Value()` which does return a `Variant`. You likely need to cast it to integer before comparing it which is why `Len() < ` is a good idea. You can explicitly cast it using `CInt()`, `CLng()` or `CDbl()` depending on the size of the numeric value.

Comment: @JNevill - It fails at the first iteration (as shown by the fact that in my tests it only prints "not blank" once). Edited question to clarify.

Comment: When you write "Not Blank" you are outside your loop. The iterations of the loop only affect the code inside. When it fails, double check the value of your counter.

Comment: If your IF statement inside the loop results in false, then you merely iterate your counter. You don't do anything else, so it's probably iterating very fast. How about before that `counter = counter + 1` line you stick a `debug.print counter` and then you can watch the iterations happen in your VBA's Immediate window.

Comment: @JNevill - :slapshead: Yep, I'm being stupid. I will add the debug.print counter when I can, and update the question with the result. (Currently all licences to the software I'm using are in use by others.)

Comment: @JNevill `Debug.Print` won't work as the OP is using the Excel VBA object modal via VBScript, but they do have their own `WriteLine()` function.

Comment: Ah! ok. I thought that `WriteLine()` was a call to a UDF. In that case, then stick `WriteLine(counter)` above the counter increment line.

Comment: @JNevill It is, VBScript doesn't have an equivalent `Debug.Print` you have to write your own debugging logic like this UDF the OP is using.

Comment: Also an `Integer` in VBScript is `-32,768 to 32,767` - See [VBScript Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: That's not very much. Darned Integers. Thanks for the clarification. I've written a bit of vbscript in the past and always found it tricky to debug.

Comment: @JNevill - Many thanks for pointing out my debugging wasn't telling me how many loops it did. That ultimately allowed me to find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there are error values within the cells of the sheet.

Try

```
Do 

    val = objSheet.range(startCell).offset(counter)
    MsgBox TypeName(val)

    if VarType(val) = vbError then val = "Error"
    MsgBox val

    if val = "" then exit do

    counter = counter + 1
    MsgBox counter

Loop
```

---

To be clear:
The runtime error is thrown if the code tries to compare the Excel cell error value with the string `""`. Surely you could catch the runtime error with error handling. But then you will have much trouble to read cells after the cell containing the cell error value. So the better way here is in my opinion to check whether there is a cell error value and if so converting it into a string. So no runtime error is thrown.

If the need is exactly to know which Excel cell error value it is, then one could do:

```
...
    if VarType(val) = vbError then val = objSheet.range(startCell).offset(counter).text
    MsgBox val
...
```

Comment: Wouldn't that still error at the first line of the loop? It doesn't return `vbError` it just triggers a runtime error.

Comment: @Lankymart - Nope, it works. Axel's hit the nail on the head: I have error values in some cells in the sheet. Axel's code handles the error, preventing the Type mismatch.

Comment: @AndyT Ah right, makes sense. Like I said don't do a lot of Excel COM stuff anymore. So the actual cells contained `#ERROR` I guess.

Comment: @Lankymart - #REF in this case, but I assume the same issue would occur for #N/A and any other excel error type.

Answer (score 1):

Was just about to post but [@axel-richter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915431/axel-richter) has [beat me too it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38744036/692942).

But the issue I believe *(with a bit of toing and froing with [@jnevill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2221001/jnevill))* lies with the fact that `counter` loops around your `Do` loop so fast you reach an `Offset()` that the sheet doesn't like and it returns a

> Microsoft VBScript Runtime Error: Type mismatch

You could test this using `On Error Resume Next` to determine what the value of `Err.Source` is to see if Excel COM is raising the error.

```
counter = 0
Call writeLine(objSheet.range(startCell).offset(counter))   
If Not objSheet.range(startCell).offset(counter) = "" Then Call writeLine("not blank")

Do
    'Capture errors
    On Error Resume Next
    'If the "If" statement errors will jump over and execute the next
    'statement which will be the error check.
    If objSheet.range(startCell).offset(counter) = "" Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Call writeLine("Error: " & Err.Source & " (" & Err.Number & ") - " & Err.Description)
    End If
    'Stop capturing errors.
    On Error Goto 0
Loop
```

A simple fix would be to set a constant upper limit value

```
Const MAX_ROWS = 65536
```

<sup># `MAX_ROW` value taken from information in Related Links</sup>

Then inside the loop check you've not exceeded this value

```
If counter <= MAX_ROWS Then
    ...
End If
```

Another approach is to use `On Error Resume Next` to trigger the loop to exit.

```
Dim value
...
Do
    'Capture errors
    On Error Resume Next
    value = objSheet.range(startCell).offset(counter)
    If value = "" Or Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
    On Error Goto 0
Loop
```

---

#### Related Links

- [What is the maximum value for row and column offsets in VBA for Excel 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20425257/692942)
- [What is the maximum value for row and column Range offset in VBA/Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2146390/692942)